# Convert ANSI file text into UTF8 in node.js usinf Fyle System

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, fs

I´m trying to convert the text from an ANSI encoded file to an UTF8 encoded text in node.js.

I´m reading the info from the file using node´s core Fyle System. Is there any way to 'tell' to readFile that the encoding is ANSI?

```
fs = require('fs');
        fs.readFile('..\\\\LogSSH\\' + fileName + '.log', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
```

If not, how can I convert that text?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, ANSI is not actually an encoding. But no matter what exact encoding we're talking about I can't see any Microsoft code pages included in the relatively short list documented at [Buffers and Character Encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings):

- `ascii` - for 7-bit ASCII data only. This encoding is fast and will strip the high bit if set.
- `utf8` - Multibyte encoded Unicode characters. Many web pages and other document formats use UTF-8.
- `utf16le` - 2 or 4 bytes, little-endian encoded Unicode characters. Surrogate pairs (U+10000 to U+10FFFF) are supported.
- `ucs2` - Alias of 'utf16le'.
- `base64` - Base64 encoding. When creating a Buffer from a string, this encoding will also correctly accept "URL and Filename Safe Alphabet" as specified in RFC4648, Section 5.
- `latin1` - A way of encoding the Buffer into a one-byte encoded string (as defined by the IANA in RFC1345, page 63, to be the Latin-1 supplement block and C0/C1 control codes).
- `binary` - Alias for 'latin1'.
- `hex` - Encode each byte as two hexadecimal characters.

If you work in Western Europe you may be tempted to use `latin1` as synonym for Windows-1252 but it'll render incorrect results as soon as you print a `€` symbol.

So the answer is no, you need to install a third-party package like [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite).

Comment: @AsierPomposo How did you solve it without iconv-lite?

Comment: @DuncanLuk . I solve it changing the encoding from 'utf8' to binary in the fs.readFile(). you have the code I used above

Answer (score 3):

In my case the convertion between types was due to the need to use special latin characters as 'í' or 'ó'. I solve it changing the encoding from 'utf8' to binary in the fs.readFile() function:

```
 fs.readFile('..\\LogSSH\\' + fileName + '.log', {encoding: "binary"}, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
```